# Dont kill program on illegal behavoir

Tags: linux, c++

I have a program which tried to use freed address. when it does this, It crashes. I think this happens because Linux terminates the program for wrong behavior. Is there any to way to run program in some kind of relaxed environment where accessing freed memory will just give me warning and continue the program execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Processes are terminated by a feature named "signal", which has been in the UNIX kernel since the 1970s. The signal a process receives for accessing illegal memory is SIGSEGV (segmentation violation).

Most signals lead to termination, but a program can choose to either ignore signals of a specific type, or run a signal handling routine when the signal is delivered. While not all signals can be ignored or handled, SIGSEGV can.

This is documented in the man pages for [signal(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/signal.2.en.html) and [signal(7)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages/signal.7.en.html). However, you tagged your question with C++. Most probably, C++ has its own mechanism, based on the `signal` system call, to do that.

After writing all this, I found a C++ program that catches SIGSEGV on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/918891/3548109.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that even if you handle the signal and continue the process, you will *not* in fact have gotten access to that freed memory. SIGSEGV is (one of) the ways the kernel tells a process "I'm not going to let you do that" and you're going to have to fix your software to not try to access freed memory *anyway*.

Comment: Note how the author of that program also warns you to not *ever* actually do this.

Comment: Quite right. How such a condition is handled is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: And common wisdom about handling the condition seems to amount do "Don't, and rewrite your program instead so that the error doesn't come up in the first place"

Comment: You could issue a pretty error message and die, for example. Or provide additional context, like dumping out some data structures. At least useful during code development. It's not an entirely academic question in my opinion.

Comment: Fair, although the OP seems to be asking to actively ignore the error in an out-of-development context.

Comment: It’s not clear from the question if the program is being killed by a signal — that would only happen if the freed memory was returned to the kernel. In other cases, it could be the C library detecting the double `free` and aborting the program.

Comment: @StephenKitt That's a good point. It's not clear whether the crash is triggered by the kernel or some runtime environment; on re-reading the question, I would actually lean towards the latter. C++ (the question is tagged with C++) probably performs such a runtime checks; Java certainly does.

Answer (score 4):

Since access to unmapped memory is considered faulty behavior by applications, the termination of them is absolutely correct.

Imagine other programs accessing the memory of *your* programs on the other hand...

But you may try to use a small-footprint linux compiled without MMU-support (on a single user system only). Such a system will allow rogue memory access.

Comment: Current operating systems rely on page mapping for protection, so even if accesses to unmapped addresses were allowed, that still wouldn’t provide access to other processes’ memory — that memory is entirely inaccessible, not just because it’s not allowed, but also because it isn’t mapped.

Comment: In case one wants to read other processes memory on purpose, one can read from `/proc/*/mem`. As far as I know, you cannot, by any means, read non-mapped memory (direct physical ram access) in modern Linux from user-space.